# Custom CreateUser method (with additional parameters)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i have implemented custom MembershipProvider and now i would like to use CreateUserWizard to create new users..
the problem is that i want to store in the db more information that normally (e.g. first and last name).

There is function:

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, 
        string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey,
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

which i can implement but it won't store first name etc.

i found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1496795.aspx solution that i can overload this function and call it manually but the default CreateUser function will still be called in this case...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store FirstName and LastName fields in profile?

Comment: no, i need to update my database while registration occurs

Comment: No, really, profile is the place to store meta like this. It eliminates the need to reimplement code that is tried and true. Just hook the user created event in the wizard and update the profile for the created user.

Comment: do i have to implement custom profile provider if i want to store all personal data in my own databases?

Comment: in your own? yes. do you have a compelling reason to discard the well designed provider stack and database? I have found that in most cases the standard sql providers can be configured to meet a wide range of requirements and it ultimately saves time, money and sleep. just sayin....

Answer (score 0):

Create your own UI or I think you can override the default template using the designer, you can say convert to template, and add to this template.  You have to invoke the methods yourself though... Try tapping into the events of the control to call the correct methods.

HTH.